# Setting up Elasticsearch on Nitrous.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, nitrousio

Does anyone know how to set up elasticsearch and get it running within Nitrous.io - they've removed their autoparts function which installed it very nicely & neatly for you.

Right now it's not present on my IDE when I try and query it so I'm guessing it's not even installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months back I set up ElasticSearch on a Nitrous container - starting with the basic Nitrous Ubuntu container. I just followed the instructions for installing it on Ubuntu 14.04, which is what Nitrous use as their base image. Digital Ocean has instructions on how to set it up on this version of Ubuntu - and those are the instructions I used.  See here:

["Elastic Search on Ubuntu 14.04 - via Digital Ocean"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I got a few warnings, but they didn't seem to impact the functionality. If you get errors on 'sudo apt-get update', try starting over with a new container and skip that command.

Comment: Thanks - yeah support got back to me just after you posting this. I've accepted it as it is the correct way to set this up.